# change element position when it scrolled out of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 menus in my web that contains: menu1 menu2 content footer.

when i scroll up, i want that menu2 will stay but will be in the top (instead of menu1)
so after scroll: menu2 content footer

thanks

Comment: What is your markup? And more importantly, what have you come up with?

Comment: where is the code to fiddle with :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just made a small jsfiddle using jquery. Should be easy to understand.

HTML

```
<div id="menu1">
    Menu 1
</div>
<div id="menu2">
    Menu 2
</div>
<div id="content">
    Content
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {    
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#menu1").height() && $("#menu2").css("position") != "fixed"){
        $("#menu2").css("position", "fixed");
        $("#menu2").css("top", "0");
        $("#content").css("margin-top", $("#menu2").height() + "px");
    }
    else if($(window).scrollTop() < $("#menu1").height()  && $("#menu2").css("position") == "fixed")
    {
        $("#menu2").css("position", "");
        $("#menu2").css("top", "");
        $("#content").css("margin-top", "");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oaa1e6y2/3/

Feel free to ask if you have any questions to this.